# What substitutes Debian's ufw in Arch?

Tags: debian, arch-linux, security, iptables, utilities

When I use Debian I install `ufw` then running the following code to unfilter my desired ports:

```
ufw --force enable
ufw allow 22,25,80,443
```

As I think to move to Arch Linux I'd like to ask what substitutes Debian's ufw in Arch? Is there an Arch-native tool to easily manage the `iptables`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a "Arch-native" tool, as there are not many [Arch projects](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Category:Arch_projects) to begin with.

According to the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Category:Firewalls), Arch Linux comes with two options for managing a firewall: iptables or the newer [nftables](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nftables) project.

iptables should be installed by default, and you can install various [front-ends](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Iptables#Front-ends) like ufw or shorewall for managing its rules.

So you can simply keep using [ufw](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uncomplicated_Firewall) on Arch Linux.

Comment: Thanks. I assume I can use the code above `ufw --force enable && ufw allow 22,25,80,443` (can't test now).